# javascript set the feature date from the current date

Tags: javascript, date

How do i set the date object for feature date from the current date  using javascript.

For example,

Need to set "next month 10th"

Is it correct way, if i use

```
var d = new Date(); 
d = d.setDate(10);
```

Comment: Try to google javascript Date. There are tons of tutorials.

Comment: That will set the date part of your current date to 10. So for example if d currently holds data representing 24th April 2011, your code will change it to 10th April 2011

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var date = new Date();
date.setMonth(date.getMonth()+1);
date.setDate(10);
```

Comment: How can i add dynamically i.e(i have notification date field for feature)

Comment: Are you sure you can chain the methods like that? (Because when I tried it I got an error "Uncaught TypeError: Object 1352963993851 has no method 'setDate'"; looks like it returns the number of milliseconds since 1/1/1970.)